# How is this relation transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$$R = \{(0,1), (0,2)\}$$

I drew out a directed graph; however, I still do not see how this relation is transitive. If $0$ was reflexive, then it is transitive; however, that is clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This relation is vacuously transitive as there is no case where $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$ so the hypothesis for transitivity is never satisfied.

Comment: Would something like this be vacuously true for transitivity? R = {(0,3), (2,3)}?

Comment: Yes. Read carefully the definition.